# Selenium Webdriver Performance logging not available

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever I try to run the code below, I'm not able to access any of the performance logs from chromedriver.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? Thanks :)

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var options = new chrome.Options();
var logging_prefs = new webdriver.logging.Preferences();
logging_prefs.setLevel(webdriver.logging.Type.PERFORMANCE, webdriver.logging.Level.ALL);
options.setLoggingPrefs(logging_prefs);

var capabilities = options.toCapabilities();
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer('http://localhost:49153/wd/hub')
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .withCapabilities(capabilities)
  .build();

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/');
driver.manage().logs().get('performance').then(function(entries) {
  console.log(entries);
});
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't exactly know what you're doing wrong, but a slightly modified version of your code worked for me (OS X, ChromeDriver 2.12.301326, selenium-webdriver@2.44.0)

```js
'use strict';

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var options = new chrome.Options();
var logging_prefs = new webdriver.logging.Preferences();
logging_prefs.setLevel(webdriver.logging.Type.PERFORMANCE, webdriver.logging.Level.ALL);
options.setLoggingPrefs(logging_prefs);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/');
driver.manage().logs().get('performance').then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
driver.quit();
```

I see a load of entries like this:

```json
{ level: { value: 800, name: 'INFO' },
  message: '{"message":{"method":"Timeline.eventRecorded","params":{"record":{"children":[],"data":{},"endTime":2859429671.622,"startTime":2859429671.614,"type":"Program"}}},"webview":"A86F9CE4-1DE7-489D-BF7F-BB2F4D800CCA"}',
    timestamp: 1422539044149,
  type: '' },
{ level: { value: 800, name: 'INFO' },
  message: '{"message":{"method":"Timeline.eventRecorded","params":{"record":{"children":[],"data":{},"endTime":2859429674.514,"startTime":2859429674.477,"type":"Program"}}},"webview":"A86F9CE4-1DE7-489D-BF7F-BB2F4D800CCA"}',
    timestamp: 1422539044149,
  type: '' },
```

Comment: I am using **Selenium Grid**. With `.usingServer('http://192.168.1.113:5566/wd/hub')` an error occurs. `WebDriverError: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found`